# Understanding and And Analysing GGIR (Actigraphy)

Tags: analysis

I have very little experience in R. I have recently joined a project aiming to analyze accelerometer data using the program GGIR. I was wondering if anyone on here has had experience with processing and analysing results as I have a couple questions.

1. I am wondering how to access the direct code behind the program. Currently only a few functions are available to me but to understand it exhaustively I would like to view the code in its entirety. Is this possible?
2. For those who have experience with it already, the output visualization_sleep.pdf (from part 4) contains 4 different colors (blue, red, green and yellow/light green). I am wondering what all of these mean and whether you may already know.
3. Again pertaining to visualization_sleep, I am wondering if it is possible to produce the output of g.part 4 & 5 with accurate labels for the participant's ID numbers. Additionally, I am wondering if it is possible to produce them in ascending order as they currently are rendering in descending order.

Thank you for your time and if you need any more information please tell me!

Comment: Please ask one and only one question per question post. Besides being a rule of this site it also gives you better chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1: edit(getAnywhere(function_name)) in R console will give you the code for the function_name().